# How do you merge headers on plotly tables using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Is there any way using Plotly Pandas package to merge the duplicated header rows within a table?

I know there is a way using plotly dash (with the ***merge_duplicate_headers=True*** command) but it doesn't seem to translate

The table currently has two header lines, I want to merge the duplicated top line

[image]

This is the expected outcome (replicated in Excel)

[image]

```
table_1 = go.Table(
    header=dict(
        values=[['test_1','day 1'], ['test_1','year'],['test_2','day 1'], ['test_2','year']],
    ),
    cells=dict(values=[[1,2,3,4,5], [2014,2015,2016,2017,2018],[6,7,8,9,10], [2014,2015,2016,2017,2018]]),
)

fig = dict(data=table_1)
py.iplot(fig)
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample output or any screenshot of your current output ?

Comment: Hi, I have embedded the relevant picture of the output within the link in the description. Thanks!

Comment: Have you read [this](https://community.plot.ly/t/merge-multiple-cells-in-table/23936/6)?

Comment: What's your expected output? What do you mean by 'merge'?

Comment: @Allen I have uploaded an image of the expected outcome within the text now, thanks!

Comment: @rpanai, I had not seen that but that does look like the functionality I'm after, looks like it won't be possible! Shame. Thank you very much for highlighting it to me

Comment: @andrews does the answer I provide help you somehow or do you prefer me to delete it?

Comment: @rpanai it isn't the answer I was after unfortunately, but someone else may find it useful

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered use a `pd.DataFrame` and pass it to `plotly`?

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.offline as py

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5], [2014,2015,2016,2017,2018],
                   [6,7,8,9,10], [2014,2015,2016,2017,2018]]).T

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([['test_1', 'day 1'], ['test_1', 'year'],
                                        ['test_2', 'day 1'], ['test_2', 'year']])

df.columns = ["_".join(col) for col in df.columns]

table_1 = go.Table(
    header=dict(
        values=df.columns,
    ),
    cells=dict(values=df.values.T),
)

fig = dict(data=table_1)
py.iplot(fig)
```