# How to show Pandas Dataframe as a table in a pretty way with adjustable colspan?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly

I have a dataframe that I get from a SQL Select with an Order by condition, so that it looks like:

```json
  Class Sublcass     Value
0     A        X  0.000000
1     A        Y  0.184650
2     A        Z  1.000000
3     B        X  1.381629
4     B        Y -0.031118
```

Then I transposed it to be like:

```json
Class       A                       B
Subclass    X        Y    Z         X         Y         Z
Value     0.0  0.18465  1.0  1.381629 -0.031118  0.636372
```

Now, I want to show the dataframe as a Plotly table and with the following code, directly from the Plotly doc page

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(
    header=dict(values=list(df.columns),
                fill_color='paleturquoise',
                align='left'),
    cells=dict(values=[df[col] for col in df.columns],
               fill_color='lavender',
               align='left'))
])

fig.show()
```

[Here the resulting table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXOul.png)

But what I want instead is the Class to have a multiple column span, like
[this edited picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqg3o.png)

I already know that this can be done with `df.to_html()` but I'd prefer a Plotly solution, cause I also have to plot other types of graphs from the same dataset and thus I can then put them all together.

Edit:
If there's no solution using Plotly, even other plotting libraries are welcome, as far as I can also polt scatter and line graphs in the same subplot

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57771139/how-do-you-merge-headers-on-plotly-tables-using-pandas). Looking at the comments of that question it looks like it is not possible (note that the provided answer does not solve the problem).

Comment: @Simone I edited the post accordingly, I'm searching for any solution not strict Plotly.

Comment: You could try to implement [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53573121/plot-table-along-chart-using-matplotlib/53573651#53573651).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand your question, but see if it helps you, it's a library that allows you to visualize the data in a better way.

[image]